# Three.js render depth from texture

Tags: three.js, depth-buffer

Is it possible to somehow render to depth buffer from pre-rendered texture?

I am pre-rendering scene like original resident evil games and I would like to apply both pre-rendered depth and color texture to screen.

I previously used technique to make simpler proxy scene for depth but I am wondering if there is a way to use precise pre rendered depth texture instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`three.js` provides a [DepthTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/DepthTexture) class which can be used to save the depth of a rendered scene into a texture. Typical use cases for such a texture are post processing effects like Depth-of-Field or SSAO.

If you bind a depth texture to a shader, you can sample it like any other texture. However, the sampled depth value is sometimes converted to different representations for further processing. For instance you could compute the `viewZ` value (which is the z-distance between the rendered fragment and the camera) or convert between perspective and orthographic depth and vice versa. `three.js` provides helper functions for such tasks.

The official [depth texture](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_depth_texture) example uses these helper functions in order to visualize the scene's depth texture. The important function is:

```
float readDepth( sampler2D depthSampler, vec2 coord ) {
    float fragCoordZ = texture2D( depthSampler, coord ).x;
    float viewZ = perspectiveDepthToViewZ( fragCoordZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );
    return viewZToOrthographicDepth( viewZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );
}
```

In the example, the resulting depth value is used to compute the final color of the fragment.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like what I am looking for. I don't know much about shaders, if I understand this correctly I need to set gl_FragDepth to readDepth() is that correct?

Comment: No, in this case you don't need a depth texture but a simple depth render buffer. You normally write to `gl_FragDepth` if you compute the depth value by yourself.